# How to display two records in each rows of a table using PHP and HTML?

Tags: php, html

In my website I want to show student details in a page. I am using tables for the designing purpose. what I need is, I want to show two students in each rows. So if there are total 10 students in database, then there should be 5 rows in the display page with each rows having two students.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you would want to malform the nature of a table, but it's really just a case of outputting the same data in a different way..

Comment: simply iterate over recordset, open a TR for Odd number and close TR on Even iteration, and put student info in a TD, to format information use Table within your TD. to make it look good or DIV or P, OR SPAN whatever you like.

Comment: without code how can we help?

Comment: Please use the search function:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793716/how-to-display-two-table-columns-per-row-in-php-loop?rq=1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902356/displaying-two-column-html-table-while-php-loop?rq=1
...

Comment: share your HTML code please.

Answer (score 2):

```
$students = Array('S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'S7', 'S8', 'S9', 'S10');
$html = '<table>';
for ($i = 0; $i<count($students); $i+=2)
{
    $html.= '<tr>
                <td>'.$students[$i].'</td>
                <td>'.$students[$i+1].'</td>
            </tr>'; 
}
$html.= '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

So let's say that you have an array with your 10 students, for example `$myStudents`

To create your table try this code

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Student Name</td>
  <td>Student Name</td>
</tr>
<?php
 $cols = 2;
 $colNum=0;
 $trOpened = false;
 for($i=0;$i<count($myStudents);$i++):

    if( $colNum % 2 != 0 || $colNum==0 ){
       echo "<tr>";
        $trOpened = true;
    }
   ?>
     <td><?=$myStudents[$i]['StudentName']?></td>
 <?php
   $colNum++;
   if(  $trOpened == true && $colNum % 2 == 0 ){
        echo "</tr>";
        $trOpened = false;
        $colNum = 0;
   }

 endfor;


   ?>
</table>
```